# Displaying actual html or link from encoded json data using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following being returned from an ajax call

```
{"dataList":[{"date":"August 27, 2013","text":"<a href=\"http:\/\/www.example.com\/test.aif\" 
title=\"Click here to listen\" target=\"\">Click here to listen<\/a> to the test from
2013!"},],"record_count":3}
```

I'm adding the data to the screen by looping through it...

```
$.each(data.dataList, function(index, element) {
    $('#news_data').append($('<h1>', {
        text: element.date
    }));

    $('#news_data').append($('<h2>', {
       text: element.text                
    }));
});
```

The result is the page displaying all the html and not the actual URL. So my question is: How do I get it to actually display the link and not the HTML? Should I be returning the data in a different format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `text` property try using the `html` property such as

```
$('#news_data').append($('<h1>', {
    html: element.date
}));

$('#news_data').append($('<h2>', {
    html: element.text

}));
```

This will then append the HTML (as your data is html) to the element preserving the markup. Here is a reference to the html() function which acts similar to the html property. http://api.jquery.com/html/